# Problem in Statistics

Tags: statistics

After grading and calculating the mean, mode, median, and range of exam scores, a teacher changes the scores by adding 8 points to each student's exam score.  Which of the following measures will remain unchanged after adding 8 points to each score?

a) median  b)mean  c)mode  d)range

Answer (score 1):

The range.

Let's make a data set.

{1,2,5,10,19,21}

Min is 1

Max is 21

21-1 = 20

The range is 20.

---

Now, let's imagine that we add 8 to each score.

New Data Set:
{9,10,13,18,27,29}

Min is 9

Max is 29

29-9 = 20

The range is still 20.

Comment: Great.  I also see that one can make own list then input added value and range is the one that does not change.  Thank you.